# Покрутка страницы сайта

Tags: html, css

В моем сайте покрутка вниз работает только с помощью самой мышки имею в виду нажимаешь на мышку потом вниз работает а с помощью колесика никак не работает в чем проблема?

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, что вы имеете ввиду и еще более непонятно в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: работает только если скролл вручную двигать?

Comment: Да как бы работает когда мышка на скролле и нажимешь вверх и вниз а с помощью колесика не работает

Comment: только на вашем сайте это не работает или везде?

Comment: Только в моем..

Comment: во всех браузерах?

Comment: Я сам использую Яндекс после вашего вопроса проверил, только в Яндексе кажется

Comment: вы точно проверьте и отпишитесь

Comment: у меня щас проблемы с интернетом 1-2 часов отвечу вам и спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте консоль в браузере и покрутите колесо, если есть модули для прокрутки (напр. smooth)  - выдаст ошибку, или дайте адрес сайта.
Также, рекомендую проверить эту прокрутку сайта в других браузерах.

Comment: Блогадарю очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';` - может в этом проблема?

Так же попробуйте вручную настроить событие `onwheel`

Comment: Спасибо вам проблема решена!